# Formatting Euro prices in PHP

Tags: php, regex, euro

I try to convert some prices:

```
[0] => EUR 19,06 
[1] => 19, 70 € 
[2] => 42.53&nbsp;&euro;
[3] => 18&euro;65 
[4] => 19,99 € 
[5] => 18&euro;65
[6] => 23&euro;95 
[7] =>      19,99 &euro;
```

into this format: xx.xx €

I use this regex:

```
/(EUR|)\s*(\d{1,})\s*(\.|,|&euro;|€|)\s*(\d{1,}|)\s*(&euro;|€|&nbsp;&euro;|&nbsp;€|)\s*/
```

and this mask into a `preg_replace`:

```
$match = '${2}.$4 €';
```

It worked fine EXCEPT with the 5th entry: 19,99 €.
What is wrong with this?

Comment: Seems to work to me, https://regex101.com/r/mA7mX5/2 https://eval.in/475914 You also could decode the entities on the string before processing with regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any errors in your regex, but it could be shorter:

```
/^(?=.*(?:EUR|€|euro))\D*(\d+)\D*(\d*)\D*$/
```

and as *mask*:

```
$match = '$1.$2 €';
```

Explaining:

```
^                   # from start
(?=.*               # positive lookahead
    (?:EUR|€|euro)  # look for one of these
)                   # to take sure it is about € money
\D*(\d+)            # group at least + one digit in front of as many as possible non-digits
\D*(\d*)            # again to take the cents (* means zero or more)
\D*                 # take the remaining not digits
$                   # till the end
```

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/vC7jB9/3)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I got a problem with a new price: 85€
I updated the regex: https://regex101.com/r/vC7jB9/2 but I don't know how to full the 2nd capturing group with zeros if it's empty?

Comment: @Kernel. Look into version 3 of the regex. But, this regex is just _remodeling_ the number positions, if you want to add zeroes, you will need one function or another regex to do it against the result of the atual regex.